# Add the same data to the list, with scan QR Code google vison

Tags: java, android, android-camera, google-vision

I use to scan Qr Code Google Vison but I have a little problem. When scan QR Code 
It automatically saves me several objects the same. How do if you scan QR Code read one data.

For example:

my class Employee

model object  Employee

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String age;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String age) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
```

}

ScanQrCode.class

method with read scanning Qr Code

```
private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

...
```

//this method with read vale with QR Code

```
 @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) text.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        vibrator.vibrate(400);

String name,lastname,age;
String[] dataEmployee = new String[3];
barcodeString = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;

 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<z[0-9]>(.+?)</z[0-9]>");

      if (p.matcher(barcodeString).matches()) {
          Matcher m = p.matcher(barcodeString);
                 while (m.find()) {
                      dataEmployee[index] = m.group(1);
                      index++;
                  }
name = dataEmployee[0];
lastname = dataEmployee[1];
age = dataEmployee[2];


Employee empmoo = new Employee(name,lastname,age);

employeeList.add(empmoo);
}
```

Comment: do u want to display the data after scanning a qr code ????

Comment: yes , next activity is list Employee

Comment: Okay i am trying give 2 more days .thank you for your patience